# How to record OBS Studio in full screen?

Tags: obs

I'm new to [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com) and have just recorded a video.

Once the recording completed, I realized that the produced video was not in full screen.

There is a blank area mark with X as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I only noticed this issue when I replayed the recorded video with VLC.

How do I fix this problem?

I would like to record the video in full screen, not half of the screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the blank area > Resize output (source size)